# Playing non-iTune music files on iPhone SE

Tags: iphone, itunes, music, library

I recently used CopyTrans Control to copy music files from my PC to my iPhone.  When I try to access my library of music on the iPhone, I keep getting blocked by an "Account" screen requiring me to join Apple Music.  When I plug my iPhone into my PC, I can see the music files I copied but I can't play them.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Apple has never required anyone to join Apple Music. Some people have reported a bug that causes this screen to get stuck (https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7313495?tstart=0), but this appears to refer to an outdated version of iOS. If you are really stuck, you can always close and reopen the Music app, or reboot the phone.